# Permission denied on a table of a view while I can directly query the table

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a weird problem. I have a table like `public.foo` where I have enabled RLS. Now I have another view like `create view app.foo_v as select * from public.foo`. When I now do a `select * from public.foo` everything is fine and working as expected. But when I do `select * from app.foo_v` I get an error like this:

> SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation foo

What privilege am I missing here?

EDIT 1:
This behavior remains even if I disable RLS temporarily

EDIT 2:

```
-- as postgres
create schema report;
create user app_user with password 'a';
create user view_user with password 'a';
create user app_admin with password 'a';

grant all on schema report to view_user;
grant app_user to app_admin;
grant view_user to app_admin;

-- as app_user
create table fooo(name varchar);

-- as view_user
create view report.foo_v as select * from public.fooo;

-- as app_admin
select * from public.fooo;
select * from report.foo_v;
```

PS I am running: PostgreSQL 10.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: This has nothing to do with RLS. Who are the owners of the view and table, what are the ACLs on them, and who is running the query?

Comment: owner of the view is user A and I use user B which has role A. owner of the table is user C and B has role C.

Comment: I would add a reproducible test case in SQL to the question. That would make it more answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your view_user is missing the SELECT privilege on the underlying table.

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE fooo IN SCHEMA public to view_user;
```

As you describe in the comment it could be solved as well if user A is getting role C.

Comment: indeed seems that the view owner need to have select permissions on the underlying table even if the executing user has this privilege.